# maven clean fails on target directory

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, build

I want to run maven from within IntelliJ/eclipse with `mvn clean install` to build and install my projects.

Sometimes when using an IDE to build, maven complains about not being able to delete some files within the *target*-directory. This does not seem to happen if I only use command-line tools and don't open use any IDE at all.
However, it consumed a whole lot of time for many people I know, including me.

When using eclipse it's usually some *.jar or so that is locked. Usually after closing eclipse you are able to delete it manually.

When I used IntelliJ to build, it created two folders that neither maven nor me can delete. Even after closing any IDE and restarting my computer. Those directories seem to be empty but when I try to open one of them I get a message saying `this file or directory is corrupted and cannot be read`:

[image: this file or directory is corrupted and cannot be read]

I also tried removing it using windows explorer. It seems to successfully delete the files, outputs no error but the files still remain undeleted.

When using bash and `rm -rf target/` I got the following error:

```
$ rm -rf target/
rm: cannot remove 'target/liferay-work/appServerPortalDir/html/js/editor/tiny_mce/plugins/fullscreen': File exists
rm: cannot remove 'target/liferay-work/appServerPortalDir/html/js/editor/tiny_mce/plugins/iespell': Directory not empty
```

I have already disabled my windows search indexing and disabled indexing for *.jar explicity but it didn't help.

Does someone know how to prevent this or how I can delete these folders now?

Could this have to do with pathnames that are getting too long (speaking of the 256 char pathname limit of windows)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to find out which process locks the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle and Unlocker were unable to help me. 
Somehow a 0-byte file was created during work with IntelliJ and Maven. 
After I restarted and ran chkdsk.exe I was able to remove that folder / files.